# Unable to get a token on a nodejs backend

Tags: node.js, jwt, backend, bcrypt, payload

I used to get my signin token using this code:

```
1const { authSecret } = require('../.env');
2const jwt = require('jwt-simple');
3const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
4
5module.exports = app => {
6  const signin = async (req, res) => {
7    if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
8     return res.status(400).send('Enter user and password ');
9    };
10
11    const user = await app.db('users')
12      .where({ email: req.body.email })
13      .first()
14
15    if (!user) return res.status(400).send('User not found!');
16
17    const isMatch = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password);
18    if (!isMatch) return res.status(401).send('Invalid email/password!');
19
20    const now =  Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
21
22    const payload = {
23      id: user.id,
24      name: user.name,
25      email: user.email,
26      age: user.age,
27      city: user.city,
28      iat: now,
29      exp: now + (60 * 60 * 24 * 7)
30    };
31
32    res.json({
33      ...payload,
34      token: jwt.encode(payload, authSecret)
35    })
36  };
37
38  const validadeToken = async (req, res) => {
39    const userData = req.body || null;
40      try {
41        if (userData) {
42            const token = jwt.decode(userData.token, authSecret)
43            if(new Date(token.exp * 1000) > new Date()) {
44              req.send(true)
45            }
46        }
47      } catch (e) {
48        console.log('Inspired token');
49      };
50
51      res.send(false);
52  };
53
54  return { signin, validadeToken };
55}
56
```

But yesterday I tried to create a new node project  with `"bcrypt-nodejs": "^0.0.3"` and `"jwt-simple": "^0.5.6"`, but now I'm getting this error message when I try to login on my backend and getting the token that doesn't appear

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
(node:13188) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Require key
    at Object.jwt_encode [as encode] (F:\react_native\Expo\base\track-server\node_modules\jwt-simple\lib\jwt.js:123:11)
    at signin (F:\react_native\Expo\base\track-server\api\auth.js:34:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:13188) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13188) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Does anyone know what I shuld do to get this signin token?

Comment: I would not use the package `bcrypt-nodejs` as that package was depreciated a long time ago. Instead use the package `bcrypt` located at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt

Comment: I also have bcrypt lib on this project, but I can't just change the bcypt-nodejs lib to bcrypt on line 3, can I?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `authSecret` variable is `undefined`, thus resulting in the `Error: Require key` error when you try to use it as the key during the `jwt.encode(payload, authSecret)` call on line 34.

As you already appear to have a `.env` file, I would suggest using the `dovenv` module here https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

So assuming your `.env` file is in the root directory of your project. Replace your destructured import `const { authSecret } = require('../.env');` with

```js
require('dotenv').config();

const authSecret = process.env.authSecret;
```

(obviously replacing `authSecret` with whatever the environment variable defined in your `.env` file is). Also just FYI it is convention to make environment variable upper case and separated by underscores. e.g. `AUTH_SECRET`

Comment: Thank you, but I also have an API for users where I make the signup of the users that also show this error, but the user is being registered.
You can see my GITHUB https://github.com/GlaudistonNeto/blogRnV4 repository where I sent the project before trying the sign-in and after the register. I didn't use the env file there because I didn't need it. If you can help me trying something there too, I'd be very glad.
Thank you for the help

Comment: @GNeto sorry i'm not sure i understand the question, are you sure it is the same error? I looked through your github repo but didn't see any places where you are using the `jwt-simple` module, and it is that module when you call `jwt.decode` without a key that is giving the error.

Comment: Exactly. What I tried to say was that in my Github there's this repository before I try with the jwt-simple, after I try it, I got the error end I tried to get some help here.
I just wanted to show you my full repository where I'm trying to register and signin a user.